# ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am really new to postgres. The question looks very simple but I just cant see where I got wrong.

I a table created as follows:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t(
        tn VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(tn)
    );
```

I want to insert an instance if the instance does not exist. Here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO t (tn) 
VALUES 
(SELECT 'q' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t WHERE tn = 'q')) ;
```

And the psql console keeps giving me the error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
```

I have checked every piece of code individually, for instance both

```
SELECT 'q' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t WHERE tn = 'q');
```

and

```
INSERT INTO t (tn) VALUES ('p');
```

run without error. But error occurs when I put them together.

Does anyone know where I got wrong..?

Comment: Nitpick, but "postgres" or "postgresql". There's no such thing as "postgre" or "postgress". Yes, we know the name is stupid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lose `VALUES` and the brackets...

```
INSERT INTO t (tn) 
SELECT 'q' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t WHERE tn = 'q');
```